# Help with median in ruby

Tags: ruby, median

I am writing a ruby script that will get numbers and output the median. This is my code

```
numbers = Array.new    
numbers = [gets]     
def median(numbers)     
    sorted = numbers.sort
    mid = numbers.length/2 sorted[mid] 
    numbers.push mid    
end 
end
```

When you run it, it asks for the numbers but won't give the median...

Answer (score 3):

```
def median(array)
  array.sort!
  if array.length % 2 == 0
    median_value = (array[array.length / 2] + array[array.length/2 - 1]) / 2.0
  else
    median_value = array[array.length / 2]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You never call the median method, you only define it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework assignment?

First make sure your inputs are what you think they are. I placed your code in a file called median.rb and then ran rdebug. Note the contents of the numbers array after the *[gets]*

```
$ rdebug median.rb
median.rb:1
numbers = Array.new
(rdb:1) n
median.rb:2
numbers = [gets] 
(rdb:1) n
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
median.rb:5
def median(numbers) 
(rdb:1) p numbers
["1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n"]
(rdb:1) p numbers[0]
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7\n"
(rdb:1) p numbers[0].class
String
(rdb:1)
```

Comment: yes this is a homework assignment. The textbook is crap and doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some monkeypatches I use on Enumerable, including one for median:

```
module Enumerable
  # Does not sort the values; do this yourself before calling if you like
  def median( &blk )
    values = blk ? map( &blk ) : self
    values[ values.length / 2 ]
  end
  def sum( &blk )
    values = blk ? map( &blk ) : self
    values.inject(0){ |sum,v| sum + v }
  end
  def average( &blk )
    (length==0) ? 0 : (sum( &blk ) * 1.0 / length)
  end
  alias_method :avg, :average
  def std_dev( &blk )
    values = blk ? map( &blk ) : self
    mean = values.average
    Math.sqrt( values.map{ |value| (value-mean)*(value-mean) }.average )
  end
  def dups_by
    keyvals = Hash.new{|h,v|h[v]=[]}
    each{ |v|   keyvals[yield(v)] << v }
    result = []
    keyvals.each{ |k,v| result << v if v.length > 1 }
    result
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a few issues here:

1. You have an extra `end` keyword that from what you've posted here isn't needed.
2. `gets` returns a string. For example, you can collect the numbers space delimited and create an array from this.
3. You aren't calling `median`, which is why it won't give you the median.

So something like this will work:

```
def median(numbers)     
    sorted = numbers.sort
    numbers[numbers.length/2]  
end 

p median(gets.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Enumerable::Statistics](https://github.com/mrkn/enumerable-statistics)

```rb
require 'enumerable/statistics'

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.median # => 3
```

`mean` `variance` `stdev` `mean_variance` `mean_stdev` `median` `percentile` `value_counts` `histogram` are available.